# Use the index from form1 and use it in form2

Tags: c#, winforms

So in the form 1 I have a datagridview, and when the users wants to edit any of the clients, he picks one and click the edit button... and appears a new window

In the new window I want that in the textbox 1 is the client's name, and textbox 2 the address.

Here is the code of the form1

```
    public void Clientesgrid_Cellclick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = clientesgrid.SelectedRows[0].Index;
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing in the form1? How can I take the index to the other form? Help.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is probably to include it in the constructor for `Form2`.  So in `Form2` you'd have something like this:

```
public Form2(int clientID)
{
    // Do something with the clientID
    // Most likely set it to a property on Form2, or a private member.
}
```

Then in `Form1` when you create an instance of `Form2` it might look something like this:

```
var index = clientesgrid.SelectedRows[0].Index;
var editForm = new Form2(index);
editForm.Show();
```

*Ideally* you want this parameter to be the identifier for the Client, *not* simply a row index from the `DataGridView` on `Form1`.  The reason for this is because if it's just a row index and the row contains the data you need then `Form2` doesn't have what it needs, it's still dependent on `Form1` to get more data.

Reduce dependencies as much as possible.  Any instance of `Form2` should require in its constructor whatever it needs in order to do its job.  Then any other form can create an instance of `Form2` as long as it can provide what it needs.

If `Form2` *always* needs this identifier, then you might take the additional step to make its parameterless constructor private:

```
private Form2() { }
```

This would prevent other forms from creating an instance of `Form2` without providing the necessary value that it needs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass it somehow to second form, like this for example

```
public void Clientesgrid_Cellclick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    form2.RowIndex = clientesgrid.SelectedRows[0].Index;
}
```

Comment: Thats one way.  Or if there is an ownership chain you can set the index as a property and reference `((form1)Owner).Index`. Or you can include it as a constructor parameter `new form2(Index);`.  In other words...form2 wont have access to Index unless you give form2 access to index.

Answer (score 0):

create a `public` or `internal` property / field on Form2

```
class Form2
{
    internal int RowIndex; // or  internal int RowIndex {get; set;}
}
```

Call it like

```
public void Clientesgrid_Cellclick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    form2.RowIndex = clientesgrid.SelectedRows[0].Index;
}
```